# Windows Workflow 4 - when are tracking records emitted?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a long running activity (where the activity is continually doing work for a long period of time - *not* an activity that is waiting for a response from an external source) and I want to report progress from that activity. However, I cannot get this to work.

I have a simple console app that runs the activity:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new ActivityLibrary.ProgressActivity());

        var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        wfApp.Completed = e => autoResetEvent.Set();
        wfApp.Extensions.Add(new ConsoleTrackingParticipant());
        wfApp.Run();
        autoResetEvent.WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

internal class ConsoleTrackingParticipant : TrackingParticipant
{
    protected override void Track(TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(record.EventTime.ToString());
    }
}
```

I've tried implementing the ProgressActivity in two ways. First I tried deriving from CodeActivity, but when I use this implementation I receive all the custom tracking records together once the workflow has completed (though the reported record.EventTime is correct):

```
public sealed class ProgressActivity : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var customTrackingRecord = new CustomTrackingRecord("ProgressTrackingRecord")
                {
                    Data = { { "Progress", i * 10.0 }}
                };

            context.Track(customTrackingRecord);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I then tried deriving from AsyncCodeActivity, but in this case I get an "ObjectDisposedException: An ActivityContext can only be accessed within the scope of the function it was passed into" on the context.Track line:

```
public sealed class ProgressActivity : AsyncCodeActivity
{
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        Action action = () =>
            {
                for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    var customTrackingRecord = new CustomTrackingRecord("ProgressTrackingRecord")
                    {
                        Data = { { "Progress", i * 10.0 } }
                    };

                    context.Track(customTrackingRecord);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            };

        context.UserState = action;
        return action.BeginInvoke(callback, state);
    }

    protected override void EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ((Action)context.UserState).EndInvoke(result);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain where I've gone wrong?

P.S. I realise that the approach I've shown would not scale well if the workflow was ever to run on a server, but the application I'm building is a desktop application.

[EDIT]
I guess I'm actually asking a broader question here: when are tracking records emitted by the workflow execution engine? My investigations suggest that all the records for a specific activity are emitted *after* the activity has completed. Is there any way to force them to be emitted during the execution of the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also asked this question on the MSDN workflow forum, and done some further investigation myself based on the comments I received there. As a result I think that tracking records are emitted when the activity completes *or* is bookmarked. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/8ce5dee9-9a19-4445-ad7f-33e181ec228b for more info.

Comment: I would guess a more exact description is that tracking records are emitted when the workflow has no current work items on the scheduler - this is when the activity completes, or when it bookmarks itself and goes idle, waiting to be restored.

I think there is also an option somewhere to turn on emit tracking record upon first scheduled.

Comment: Tim, I would love to know what that option is! I'm finding it very hard to find this kind of information.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a side behavior of TrackingParticipant... Try NOT extending TrackingParticipant and see if that makes a difference.

Workflow extensions do not have to extend any base class or implement any interface.  Any object can be an extension.

I have made extensions that don't extend from anything, and they operate as you expect during the lifetime of the workflow.

Comment: But then how will the extension get access to the custom tracking records containing the progress info? I don't know that much about workflow extensions...

Comment: Ah, think I've got it. I can create a ProgressExtension with a ReportProgress(double progress) method that the activity can call. No need for custom tracking records.

Comment: Although the ProgressExtension approach allows me to report progress during an activities execution, I still have an issue in that the default tracking records for the activity (Started, Executing, Closed, Completed) are still only published when the activity has completed, so I have difficulty reconciling the data from these different sources: the extension is telling me that the activity is executing but the tracking records are telling me that the activity has not yet started.

Comment: @Akash: I can't help you with that, as I've never used tracking and am not familiar with how tracking participants behave...

Answer (score 1):

Using an AsyncCodeActivity allowed me to force the tracking record to be processed when the activity starts.

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        CustomTrackingRecord customRecord = new CustomTrackingRecord("Start")
        {
            Data =
            {
            {"Date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()},
            }
        };

        context.Track(customRecord);


        var executeDelegate = new Action(FakeWork);
        context.UserState = executeDelegate;
        return executeDelegate.BeginInvoke(callback, state);

    }

    private void FakeWork() {
        // do nothing
        // This allows the CustomTrackingRecord to be handled by the WorkFlowTracker 
        // so that we can identify the start of the activity.
        // The real work is done synchronously in the EndExecute method.
    }

    protected override void EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result) {

        var executeDelegate = (Action)context.UserState;
        executeDelegate.EndInvoke(result);

        Execute(context);
    }

    protected  void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
       // Do Work
    }
```

Comment: Nice. I'm no longer developing using WWF, but this seems much simpler than the approach I ended up with which involved bookmarking the activity.